# MariaDB - UPDATE/DELETE fails silently

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb, amazon-rds, r-dbi

My `data` table sits in AWS-RDS under a MariaDB instance and looks as follows:

```
| id | first | second | third | fourth | fifth | sixth |
|----|-------|--------|-------|--------|-------|-------|
|  3 | foo   | foo    | foo   | foo    |     1 | foo   |
|  4 | foo   | foo    | foo   | foo    |     2 | foo   |
|  5 | bar   | foo    | bar   | foo    |     3 | bar   |
|  6 | bar   | bar    | bar   | bar    |     4 | bar   |
|  7 | bar   | bar    | bar   | bar    |     5 | bar   |
```

UPDATE or DELETE queries fail to produce the desired output without returning any error:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), group = "aws-rds")
dbSendQuery(con, statement = "UPDATE data SET second = 'bar' WHERE id = 4;")
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Returns:

> SQL  UPDATE data SET second = 'bar' WHERE id = 4;
>    ROWS Fetched: 0 [complete]
>         Changed: 1

The table seems unchanged however since reading it in returns the original table:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), group = "aws-rds")
data.tbl <- dbReadTable(con, "data") %>% as_tibble()
dbDisconnect(con)
data.tbl
```

Returns:

```
| id | first | second | third | fourth | fifth | sixth |
|----|-------|--------|-------|--------|-------|-------|
|  3 | foo   | foo    | foo   | foo    |     1 | foo   |
|  4 | foo   | foo    | foo   | foo    |     2 | foo   |
|  5 | bar   | foo    | bar   | foo    |     3 | bar   |
|  6 | bar   | bar    | bar   | bar    |     4 | bar   |
|  7 | bar   | bar    | bar   | bar    |     5 | bar   |
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The only explanation which comes to mind is that your update is not being committed.  But, since it returned to R reporting one record changed, this is very strange.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! No clue either, no more success with delete, it returns the corresponding number of rows affected but doesn't update the table :/

Answer (score 0):

From `?dbSendQuery`

> This method is for SELECT queries only. Some backends may support data manipulation queries through this method for compatibility reasons. However, callers are strongly encouraged to use dbSendStatement() for data manipulation statements.

Try using `dbSendStatement`.